# Reduce image colors based on colorlookup table excluding transparent

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert, remap

I'm trying to reduce the number of colors in the image below using -remap in imagemagick.

olympic-logo.png
[image: olympic-logo.png]

colortable.png which consists of this two color A12E64, FF0000

[image]

Using the following code:

```
convert olympic-logo.png +dither -remap colortable.png olympic-logo-remap.png
```

Output: 
olympic-logo-remap.png

[image]

Expected Output:
olympic-logo-expected.png
[image]

Is there a way to ignore transparent area so It won't get mapped to get the expected output?

Thanks and more power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a copy of the original image to one side before doing what you already did and then restore the alpha from that afterwards like this:

```
convert rings.png -write MPR:orig +dither -remap colortable.png MPR:orig -compose copyalpha -composite result.png
```

where `MPR:` is a *"Memory Program Register"*, i.e. a named lump of RAM.

[image]

Comment: Thank you works great. Replaced copyalpha to copy-opacity. Quick question. Is there a way to flatten this without losing transparency since when you use this image to pdflib you only get outlines of the circle.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `pdflib`, but questions, and answers ;-) are free and you'll get more exposure if you ask a new question showing what you are trying to do rather than in the comments section of an already answered question. Good luck!

Comment: `Is there a way to flatten this without losing transparency`. There is nothing to flatten in your image other than transparency. PNG does not support multiply layers, so you only have one RGBA layer. The only thing is to flatten the alpha with some background color so that it could potentially be converted to JPG (or PNG). I am not familiar with PDFLIB. But try my solution below by add code to Mark Setchell's solution to make the background a solid black first before the -remap

Answer (score 2):

Your input image does not have a constant background color. It is mostly black with a large white border. You can see that if you turn alpha off:

```
convert olympic-logo.png -alpha off aoff.png
```

[image]

So you can modify Mark Setchell's command by adding **-background black -alpha background** to it.

```
convert xc:"#A12E64" xc:"#FF0000" +append colortable.png

convert olympic-logo.png -background black -alpha background -write MPR:orig +dither -remap colortable.png MPR:orig -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Does this now work for you? If not, try making the background all white.

Comment: Though my problem is already solved.  this still helps. thanks a lot.